# Jmeter- Thread Group- Thread Properties

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

Our requirement is to execute

- 1 user/thread,  10 requests/sec, Total requests = 10,000

With current Thread Properties not able to achieve.

[image]

Only one user/thread send 10 request/sec and total should be 10000 requests. Any other way to achieve this in Jmeter ?

Is following approach is correct ? We used Loop controller. So each request will repeat 10 times

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You will be able to achieve 10 requests/second with 1 virtual user only if your response time will be 100 milliseconds**. If response time will be more than 100 milliseconds - you will not be able to reach the desired load.

If your application fails to respond in 100 milliseconds time frame - most probably you've found a [performance bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and you can report this to your application developers.

If you have some time to investigate the issue you can try to provide more information, i.e. what is the average response time, what are minimum, maximum, [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), the actual number of requests per second, etc, all this information can be retrieved using [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener.

Normally when people are looking for the answer if the application under test can support X requests per second they use > 1 virtual user as load test should represent real life usage of the system under test and 1 thread (virtual user) isn't normally associated with performance testing and derivatives.

So probably you should reconsider your approach to testing and try increasing the number of threads (virtual users). The throughput can be controlled using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer). However be aware that the above timers can only **pause** JMeter to slow it down to the desired throughput. Another approach is using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination, they can be connected using [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will kick off extra threads in order to reach/maintain the desired number of requests per second.

You can install Concurrency Thread Group and Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: I have updated the question with new approach using Loop controller. As currently not worried about response time. I wanted to know with above approach does Jmeter blindly sends 10 requests per second irrespective of completion time or Jmeter waits to complete the each request within seconds and send next request ?